# No horizontal spacing within minipage

Tags: beamer, spacing, minipage

I do not understand why my attempts to introduce horizontal spacing in beamer (with hspace or typographical spacing) fail when within a minipage:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\begin{document}
  \frame{
    text \\
    \hspace{1cm} text \\
    \begin{minipage}{5cm}
      text \\
      \hspace{1cm} \quad text
    \end{minipage}
  } 
\end{document}
```

Why? How can I introduce this spacing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The command `\hspace{}` won't be effective at the start of a line inside the `minipage`. You should use `\hspace*{1cm}` or `\null\hspace{1cm}`. As David notes the `\null` version should not be used at the start of the line at paragraph begining.

A MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\frame{
    text \\
    \hspace*{1cm} text \\
    \begin{minipage}{5cm}
      text \\
      \hspace*{1cm} \quad text
    \end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `\null` version would be OK after `\\ ` but not at the start of a line that starts a paragraph.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks. Added to the answer.