# Definition of a Multiple Choice Question Style for Beamer

Tags: beamer, enumerate, tcolorbox, minipage

For asking multiple choice questions in presentations, I would like to define some commands that aid highlighting answers. The answers should possibly be over multiple lines.

To do so, one working solution currently looks like this:

```
\documentclass[compress,aspectratio=169,12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\correctAnswer}[1]{ \colorbox{green}{
        \hspace{-0.6cm}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{13cm}
      \hspace{0.3cm}
      #1
    \end{minipage}
    } }
\newcommand{\wrongAnswer}[1]{ \colorbox{red}{
        \hspace{-0.6cm}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{13cm}
      \hspace{0.3cm}
      #1
    \end{minipage}
    } }
\newcommand{\unknownAnswer}[1]{ \colorbox{white}{
        \hspace{-0.6cm}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{13cm}
      \hspace{0.3cm}
      #1
    \end{minipage}
    } }
    
\newcommand{\correctAnswerBlock}[1]{\alt<2>      
        {\unknownAnswer{#1}}
        {\correctAnswer{#1}}
    }
    
\newcommand{\wrongAnswerBlock}[1]{\alt<2>      
        {\unknownAnswer{#1}}
        {\wrongAnswer{#1}}
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Questions}
  \begin{onlyenv}<1>
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Are there questions from your side?
    \end{itemize}
  \end{onlyenv}
  \begin{onlyenv}<2-3>
    What is true regarding reductions?
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item \wrongAnswerBlock{If we can reduce a Problem $C$ to problem $D$ by a polynomial \par \hspace{0.3cm} algorithm $A_T$ ($C \leq_p D$), than both problems are in $\mathcal{P}$.}
      \item \wrongAnswerBlock{If we can reduce a Problem $D$ to problem $C$ by a polynomial \par \hspace{0.3cm} algorithm $A_T$ ($D \leq_p C$), than both problems are in $\mathcal{P}$.}
      \item \wrongAnswerBlock{Given a reduction $A_T$ of a problem $C$ to a problem $D$ ($C \leq_p D$), \par \hspace{0.3cm} we know that iff input $\alpha \in D$, than $A_T(\alpha) \in C$.}
      \item \correctAnswerBlock{Given a reduction $A_T$ of a problem $C$ to a problem $D$ ($C \leq_p D$), \par \hspace{0.3cm} we know that iff input $\alpha \in C$, than $A_T(\alpha) \in D$.}
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{onlyenv}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This produces correct output:
[image: Example Output of Questions]

Unfortunately, it requires adding `\par \hspace{0.3cm}` for every line break, because otherwise, the `minipage` would start the newline too far left. Adding the negative `hspace` is unfortunately necessary, because otherwise, the `colorbox` would insert some space:
[image: Example without the negative hspace]
Also, adding negative `vspace` (or `\hspace*`, like suggested in [No horizontal spacing within minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73726/no-horizontal-spacing-within-minipage)) did not solve the problem.

Alternatively, it is possible to use `tcbox`:

```
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\tcbset{colframe=white,
  colback=white,
  coltext=black,
  varwidth upper}
\newcommand{\correctAnswer}[1]{ \tcbox[colback=green, left=0cm, top=0cm, bottom=0cm]{#1} }  
\newcommand{\wrongAnswer}[1]{ \tcbox[colback=red, left=0cm, top=0cm, bottom=0cm]{#1} }
\newcommand{\unknownAnswer}[1]{ \tcbox[colback=white, left=0cm, top=0cm, bottom=0cm]{#1}}
```

This works, but breaks the alignment of the items:

[image: Example with tcolbox]

Setting `boxsep` (like in [Set line spacing in tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211914/set-line-spacing-in-tcolorbox)) and other parameters did not change the problem of the alignment, and the both the `halign` and `valign` property do not seem to change the anchor.

Even after fiddling for a while, I could not find a solution for this (except the `\par \hspace{-0.6cm}` solution, which is not very nice). Is there a solution for getting a colored box around my text, that is correctly aligned inside an enumerate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually adjusting the spacing, you could change the `\fboxsep`:

```
\documentclass[compress,aspectratio=169,12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0.3cm}

\newcommand{\correctAnswer}[1]{\colorbox{green}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}
      #1
    \end{minipage}%
    }}
\newcommand{\wrongAnswer}[1]{\colorbox{red}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}
      #1
    \end{minipage}%
    }}
\newcommand{\unknownAnswer}[1]{\colorbox{white}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}
      #1
    \end{minipage}%
    }}
    
\newcommand{\correctAnswerBlock}[1]{\alt<2>      
        {\unknownAnswer{#1}}
        {\correctAnswer{#1}}
    }
    
\newcommand{\wrongAnswerBlock}[1]{\alt<2>      
        {\unknownAnswer{#1}}
        {\wrongAnswer{#1}}
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Questions}
  \begin{onlyenv}<1>
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Are there questions from your side?
    \end{itemize}
  \end{onlyenv}
  \begin{onlyenv}<2-3>
    What is true regarding reductions?
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item \wrongAnswerBlock{If we can reduce a Problem $C$ to problem $D$ by a polynomial \par  algorithm $A_T$ ($C \leq_p D$), than both problems are in $\mathcal{P}$.}
      \item \wrongAnswerBlock{If we can reduce a Problem $D$ to problem $C$ by a polynomial \par algorithm $A_T$ ($D \leq_p C$), than both problems are in $\mathcal{P}$.}
      \item \wrongAnswerBlock{Given a reduction $A_T$ of a problem $C$ to a problem $D$ ($C \leq_p D$), \par  we know that iff input $\alpha \in D$, than $A_T(\alpha) \in C$.}
      \item \correctAnswerBlock{Given a reduction $A_T$ of a problem $C$ to a problem $D$ ($C \leq_p D$), \par  we know that iff input $\alpha \in C$, than $A_T(\alpha) \in D$.}
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{onlyenv}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a `\tcbox` for this. If you would use a `tcolorbox` instead, all your items would have the same width and you wouldn't have to force line breaks manually:

```
\documentclass[compress,aspectratio=169,12pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
  colframe=white,
  colback=white,
  coltext=black,
  }

\newtcolorbox{answerbox}[1][]{left=0.3cm, right=0.3cm, top=0cm, bottom=0cm,box align=top,nobeforeafter,before skip=0pt,#1,ignore nobreak}

\colorlet{wrongcol}{red}
\colorlet{correctcol}{green}
  
\newcommand{\correctAnswer}[1]{%
  \only<2>{\colorlet{correctcol}{white}}%
  \raisebox{.87\baselineskip}{\begin{answerbox}[colback=correctcol]
    #1
  \end{answerbox}}%
} 
\newcommand{\wrongAnswer}[1]{%
  \only<2>{\colorlet{wrongcol}{white}}%
  \raisebox{.87\baselineskip}{\begin{answerbox}[colback=wrongcol]
    #1
  \end{answerbox}}%
}
\newcommand{\unknownAnswer}[1]{%
  \raisebox{.87\baselineskip}{\begin{answerbox}[colback=white]
    #1
  \end{answerbox}}%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Questions}
  \begin{onlyenv}<1>
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Are there questions from your side?
    \end{itemize}
  \end{onlyenv}
  \begin{onlyenv}<2-3>
    What is true regarding reductions?
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item \wrongAnswer{If we can reduce a Problem $C$ to problem $D$ by a polynomial algorithm $A_T$ ($C \leq_p D$), than both problems are in $\mathcal{P}$.}
      \item \wrongAnswer{If we can reduce a Problem $D$ to problem $C$ by a polynomial  algorithm $A_T$ ($D \leq_p C$), than both problems are in $\mathcal{P}$.}
      \item \wrongAnswer{Given a reduction $A_T$ of a problem $C$ to a problem $D$ ($C \leq_p D$),   we know that iff input $\alpha \in D$, than $A_T(\alpha) \in C$.}
      \item \correctAnswer{Given a reduction $A_T$ of a problem $C$ to a problem $D$ ($C \leq_p D$),   we know that iff input $\alpha \in C$, than $A_T(\alpha) \in D$.}
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{onlyenv}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]